# how to read from json array in codeingiter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Im trying to decode json and get value from the json code.

```
[{
    "restaurant_id":1,
    "menu_template_id":2,
    "add_food_item_a":1,
    "menu_category_id":1,
    "status":0
} ,
{
    "restaurant_id":1,
    "menu_template_id":2,
    "add_food_item_a":2,
    "menu_category_id":1,
    "status":0
}]
```

i need to read from this json and create an array with  add_food_item_a and status.

currently I'm using like this

```
public function readJson()
    {
        $json_obj = json_decode('');
        if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]) && !empty($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])) {
            $json_text = $this->cleanMe($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]);
            // now insert into user table
            $json_obj = json_decode($json_text);
        }
        return $json_obj;
    }
```

and I call this function like

```
$add_food_item_a = isset($json_obj->add_food_item_a) ? $json_obj->add_food_item_a : '';
```

but can't read from this array of json code

Comment: have you tried using `json_decode`?

Comment: user json_decode($your_array,true); then use foreach loop to travel associative array & then you can create the any are with the available associative array paramaneter

Comment: first of this is in api, i can't get touch into it.

Comment: i just updated my question with the current status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to fetch the value of 'add_food_item_a' and 'status'

```
    <?php

    $json='[{
        "restaurant_id":1,
        "menu_template_id":2,
        "add_food_item_a":1,
        "menu_category_id":1,
        "status":0
    } ,
    {
        "restaurant_id":1,
        "menu_template_id":2,
        "add_food_item_a":2,
        "menu_category_id":1,
        "status":0
    }]';

    echo "<pre>";
    $array = json_decode($json,1);
    print_r($array);
    foreach($array as $value)
    {
        echo "\n".$value['add_food_item_a'];
        echo "\n".$value['status'];
    }
```

Comment: my json code is in postman, i need to retreve as an array thats my problem

Comment: `json_decode($json_text,1);` pass 1 as an parameter to `json_decode` you will get an array

Comment: but showing an error like`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`